# Error: names and directories be unique for SG.Checked for SG which is cause error according to import logs. Any way to find it out?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

While importing website through content porter, I am getting an error that names and directories must be unique for a structure group.

In logs I have found the TCM-ID of structure group where the error raised. But I have checked the names and directories for that structure group and its child structure group in website master. But I have not found any such thing.

In BluePrinting I have number of child websites. Is it possible that this problem is in child wesites?

Give me a solution, how to find that where the problem actually existing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have seen a similar error message in this scenario:

- Importing a Structure Group that has been localized in the SOURCE before export
- Did not check the "Resolve Shared Items with Blueprint mapping" checkbox before import

The solution was to either localize the Structure Group in the target server first, then resuming the import, or to re-import with that option checked.

Either way, to answer your exact question, yes, it can be caused by a SG in a child publication having the exact same name, in which case the only solution is to rename one of them - either the one you're importing or the existing one. If you look in your Windows Event Viewer you should have an error message about this blueprint conflict that should include the TCM URI of the item causing the conflict.

Answer (score 7):

Item names must be unique within their Organizational Item (so the Folder or Structure Group they are in) in the **entire BluePrint chain**. Tridion will not allow you to create conflicting items anywhere in the BluePrint, since creating such an item in a parent publication would make the child item invalid.

The easiest way around this is to find the conflicting items in the child publications, rename them to something unique and run Content Porter again.